# Enzyme test DOM document using jsdom

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I’m trying to test a simple component in React using jsdom dependency. On my component I want to use plain javascript and I’m using document.getElementById() and enzyme is complaining about that. So I decided to try jsdom. However I don’t know if I’m passing the proper html string to it and if I need to use enzyme’s mount instead of shallow.
This is my react component code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class LikesAmount extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      totalLikes: null,
      counter: 0,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.state.counter === 0) {
      this.setState({
        totalLikes: document.getElementById('likesAmount').dataset.likes,
        counter: this.state.counter += 1,
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="likesAmount" data-likes="1000">
        <h3>Total likes: {this.state.totalLikes}</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LikesAmount;
```

And this is my react component TEST code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import jsdom from 'jsdom';
import LikesAmount from './likesAmount';

const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

const { document } = (new JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><body><div id="likesAmount" data-likes="1000"></div></body></html>')).window;
global.document = document;

const wait = () => new Promise(resolve => setImmediate(resolve));

describe('likesAmount component', () => {
  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    wrapper = shallow(<LikesAmount />);
    await wait();
    wrapper.update();
  });

  it('Return 1000 likes', async () => {
    const likes = 1000;
    expect(wrapper.find('h3').text()).toBe(`Total likes: ${likes}`);
  });
});
```

The error that I'm getting is "Cannot read property 'find' of undefined". So I suppose it has something to do with jsdom because with a normal shallow passing the component as a parameter reads me the wrapper variable assign to it and the .find method...

Comment: are you using `jest` as a test runner?

Comment: there is an option with `attachTo` from `mount` method, will it work for you? As for your test it doesn't really make sense to test the result of react. It has it's own tests

Comment: Do you really want to use document.getElementById? I think a better, more 'react appropriate' way would be to use a ref callback. IE, in your render(), you can use `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'`, and `<div id='likesAmount' ref={(el) => {this.likesAmountDiv = ReactDOM.findByNode(el); }} />`, and then you can access it like `this.likesAmountDiv.dataset.likes`. And then you don't need any other fancy stuff for your tests either.

Comment: What is the purpose of async/await in `beforeEach` method in your test? What will happen if you get rid of them?